# NSwag: how to add a description for route parameter in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, attributes, nswag

Assuming this example:

```
    [HttpGet("action/cancel/{actionID}", Name = "cancel-action")]
    async public Task<ActionResult> ActionCancel(string actionID) {
        return await DoAllTheStuffWith(actionStopID);
```

How can I make NSwag emit a description string for actionID. I tried

```
    /// <param name="actionID">the ID of the action</param>
```

without result. I've also been searching for an attribute to add the description, but I didn't find one.

Any help appreciated

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Got it. NSwag ignores the xml documentation file, if it set to another than the default name. Reverting to the default name and keeping method parameter names and route parameter names in sync made it.